# Confusion regarding symmetric and anti-symmetric relation

Tags: equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

let R
be a relation on a collection of sets defined as follows,

## R

{
(
A
,
B
)
|
A
⊆
B
}

Here, since it is an improper set, can't we take it as A=B and say that it is both symmetric and anti-symmetric relation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If it is symmetric, then from $A \subseteq B$ you get $B \subseteq A$. This is only true if there are no different sets $A,B$ in your collection with one included in the other. But you didn't tell us which collection you are thinking about.